# Ping hosts in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, ping

I have a dataframe that has 15,000 host IP addresses (IP v4 and IP v6) I am trying to check which of these hosts are up(running) by pinging the hosts.

I have the following code that I have written

```
def ping_host(hostname):
    # hostname = "10.0.0.10 #example
    print(hostname)
    if hostname != hostname:
        return "No Hostname"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + " > /dev/null 2>&1")
    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up!')
        return "Up"
    else:
        print(hostname, 'is down!')
        return "Down"
df['Host_Status'] = df['IP Addresses'].apply(ping_host)
```

This takes for ever to complete. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

I did try -

```
df['Host_Status'] = df['IP Addresses'].swifter.apply(ping_host)
```

but even that didn't increase the speed by much.

Edit 1-

I let this run using multi-threading for 5 hours using 32/64/256 threads(I think only 32 threads were working at any given point) but at the end of the script

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def ping_host(hostname):
    # hostname = "10.0.0.10 #example
    print(hostname)
    if hostname != hostname:
        return "No Hostname"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + " > /dev/null 2>&1")
    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up!')
        return "Up"
    else:
        print(hostname, 'is down!')
        return "Down"

# you can fiddle with pool size
with ThreadPool(processes=32) as t:
    df['Host_Status'] = t.map(ping_host, df['IP Addresses'])

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

there when I tried to export it I got the following error -

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 64, in _read_forever
    self._read_and_dispatch_next_frame()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 37, in _read_and_dispatch_next_frame
    direction, frame = self._read_frame()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 45, in _read_frame
    buff = readall(self._socket.recv, 4)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_io.py", line 110, in readall
    chunk = read_fn(sz - have)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_code_executor.py", line 112, in add_exec
    self.finish_exec(more)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_console_utils.py", line 210, in finish_exec
    return server.notifyFinished(more)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 226, in _req
    return super(TSyncClient, self)._req(_api, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/thrift.py", line 160, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/thrift.py", line 172, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/protocol/binary.py", line 372, in read_message_begin
    self.trans, strict=self.strict_read)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/protocol/binary.py", line 164, in read_message_begin
    sz = unpack_i32(inbuf.read(4))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/transport/__init__.py", line 32, in read
    return readall(self._read, sz)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/transport/__init__.py", line 20, in readall
    "End of file reading from transport")
_shaded_thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='End of file reading from transport')
```

Try 2 Asyncio-

After reading the dataframe I tried -

```
async def async_ping(host):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        f"/sbin/ping -c 1 {host} > /dev/null 2>&1",
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    status = await proc.wait()

    if status == 0:
        return 'Alive'
    else:
        return 'Timeout'


async def async_main(hosts):
    tasks1 = deque()
    for host in hosts:
        tasks1.append(asyncio.create_task(async_ping(host)))

    return (t1 for t1 in await asyncio.gather(*tasks1))

start = time.perf_counter()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
resp = loop.run_until_complete(async_main(df['IP Addresses'].to_list()))
loop.close()

finish = time.perf_counter()

df['Status'] = list(resp)
print(df)
print(f'Runtime: {round(finish-start,4)} seconds')
```

I ran into Blocking error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~path/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-2646fe9bd357>", line 26, in <module>
    resp = loop.run_until_complete(async_main(df['IP Addresses'].to_list()))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<ipython-input-6-2646fe9bd357>", line 20, in async_main
    return (t1 for t1 in await asyncio.gather(*tasks1))
  File "<ipython-input-6-2646fe9bd357>", line 5, in async_ping
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/subprocess.py", line 202, in create_subprocess_shell
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1514, in subprocess_shell
    protocol, cmd, True, stdin, stdout, stderr, bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 190, in _make_subprocess_transport
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 37, in __init__
    stderr=stderr, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 775, in _start
    universal_newlines=False, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Where do you think the bottleneck is?

Comment: It gets stuck on some hosts where I out get the host name printed and but the host does not respond instantly. If I could do this in parallel for multiple hosts maybe at once then it might be a little faster.

Comment: I think testing swifter against a vanilla thread pool would be interesting so posted it as a solution.

Comment: This still take 6 hours just for 5000 servers. Swifter took about the same (when it worked) I tried running a comparison but swifter just got stuck.

Comment: Thinking about the ThreadPool case, `ping -c 1` takes 10 seconds to timeout when there is no response. Perhaps `ping -c 1 -W 1 hostname` would be better (or -c 2 -W 1) to give the host 2 chances to response. Also, a small chunksize `df['Host_Status'] = t.map(ping_host, df['IP Addresses'], chunksize=1)` would work well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw this question I wanted to try to make something that used the `asyncio` module to run pings concurrently.  The below script runs my test IP addresses in ~7 seconds.  When I run the same test IP address list synchronously it takes ~127 seconds.  I used `python` version `3.8.2` and `Windows 10 OS`.  Maybe it'll work for you.

```
import asyncio
import time
from collections import deque

import pandas as pd


async def async_ping(host, semaphore):
    async with semaphore:
        for _ in range(5):
            proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
                f'C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping {host} -n 1 -w 1 -l 1',
                stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
            )
            status = await proc.wait()
            if status == 0:
                return 'Alive'

        return 'Timeout'


async def async_main(hosts, limit):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)
    tasks1 = deque()
    for host in hosts:
        tasks1.append(asyncio.create_task(
            async_ping(host, semaphore))
        )
    return (t1 for t1 in await asyncio.gather(*tasks1))


host_df = pd.read_csv('ping_ip_dest.csv')

# set concurrent task limit
limit = 256

start = time.perf_counter()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
resp = loop.run_until_complete(async_main(host_df['IP'].to_list(), limit))
loop.close()

finish = time.perf_counter()

host_df['Status'] = list(resp)
print(host_df)
print(f'Runtime: {round(finish-start,4)} seconds')

OUTPUT:
0       N. Virginia (Virginia, USA)     23.235.60.92    Alive
1               Dallas (Texas, USA)    69.162.81.155    Alive
2            Denver (Colorado, USA)   192.199.248.75    Alive
3              Miami (Florida, USA)  162.254.206.227    Alive
4      Minneapolis (Minnesota, USA)  207.250.234.100    Alive
5                 Montreal (Canada)  184.107.126.165    Alive
6          New York (New York, USA)    206.71.50.230    Alive
7   San Francisco (California, USA)      65.49.22.66    Alive
8         Seattle (Washington, USA)       23.81.0.59    Alive
9     Washington DC (Virginia, USA)    207.228.238.7    Alive
10         Buenos Aires (Argentina)     131.255.7.26    Alive
11          Amsterdam (Netherlands)   95.142.107.181    Alive
12             Copenhagen (Denmark)   185.206.224.67    Alive
13              Frankfurt (Germany)  195.201.213.247    Alive
14          London (United Kingdom)    5.152.197.179    Alive
15                   Madrid (Spain)    195.12.50.155    Alive
16                   Paris (France)    51.158.22.211    Alive
17                  Warsaw (Poland)   46.248.187.100    Alive
18      Johannesburg (South Africa)   197.221.23.194    Alive
19                  Beijing (China)    47.94.129.116    Alive
20                Hong Kong (China)     103.1.14.238    Alive
21                   Mumbai (India)   103.120.178.71    Alive
22                 Shanghai (China)   106.14.156.213    Alive
23                    Tokyo (Japan)     110.50.243.6    Alive
24                         Brisbane   223.252.19.130    Alive
25                           Sydney      101.0.86.43    Alive
26                Tel-Aviv (Israel)   185.229.226.83    Alive
27                             Test    47.94.129.115  Timeout
Runtime: 3.1945 seconds
```

Comment: I tried this on mac and I get BlockingIOError please see the details in my original question.

Comment: Did you throw all 15,000 ip addresses at it at once? You may need to throttle the amount of hosts you ping simultaneously due to OS constraints. Try debugging the code on a handful of addresses.

Comment: @Steve_Greenwood I updated the asyncio script to include a concurrent task limit.

Comment: I am using `import grequests` before this the code would work individually but when I combine it it would get stuck. 

I just have 
`import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import grequests` and the code will get stuck on python 3.7.4

Comment: @Steve_Greenwood I don't understand what you mean, I'm not using those packages and unless its an OS specific issue they are not needed to run the above script.

Comment: I am using that in the script to query the hosts that are active using the grequests module. Importing grequests module breaks the scripts. Do you happen to know why that could be the case?

Comment: @Steve_Greenwood I have no idea, i have not used grequests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a thread pool.

**Updated** for parameter to timeout ping after 1 second, chunksize 1, more threads and skipping intermediate shell - worked for a small number of IP addresses on my local machine duplicated to 14000 total. Wait time and chunksize may be the most important. By default, ping times out after 10 seconds and threadpool runs 14000/threadcount pings before returning to the main thread. Considering a timeout was hit when testing this code, the updates should be a good improvement.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import subprocess as subp

def ping_host(hostname):
    # hostname = "10.0.0.10 #example
    print(hostname)
    if hostname != hostname:
        return "No Hostname"
    response = subp.run(["ping","-c", "1", "-W", "1", hostname], stdout=subp.DEVNULL,
        stderr=subp.DEVNULL).returncode
    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up!')
        return "Up"
    else:
        print(hostname, 'is down!')
        return "Down"

# you can fiddle with pool size

with ThreadPool(processes=128) as t:
    df['Host_Status'] = t.map(ping_host, df['IP Addresses'],
        chunksize=1)
```

Comment: Tried this and ran into an error I have posted the error and details in the original question.

Comment: @tdelaney my comment was in reference to the asyncio script, I either commented in the wrong box or my comment moved with an edit.  Sorry for the confusion.  I have moved my comment to the correct comment box.